Identify this TV Show - Australian Kids TV show 90s/00s
I remember watching a kids tv show in the late 90s / early 2000s about a kid or some kids who go to stay with a relative or something.
They're definitely by the beach or somewhere and I think there was a marine park involved like sea world.
I've read through this list of Australian Kids show titles but nothing has jumped out at me.

Could it be Ocean Star?
From Wikipedia:

Trent and Dylan Steadman are city kids who are sent by their mother to
  live with their father in a small seaside town. They struggle to make
  friends with the local kids. Trent meets Swamy, an old pearl diver who
  tells him about a priceless cluster of pearls known as the 'Ocean
  Star' that he claims were lost when his boat sunk in a cyclone forty
  years ago. The quest for the treasure sends Trent and the kids on an
  exciting and dangerous adventure.



Sure it's not 'Ship to Shore'?
That show was awesome.
Wikipedia:

The show centers around the lives of a group of children living on
  Circe Island, a fictional island off the coast of Perth, in Western
  Australia. Three series of the show were shot in 1992, 1993 and 1996.
  Each episode was 24 minutes long. The first series features comedy
  episodes of the children outwitting adults, particularly Hermes
  Endakis, played by Greg Carroll. The lead roles among the children
  were played by Clinton Voss, Jodi Herbert, Cleonie Morgon-Wootton and
  Heath Miller. Later series continued the comic tradition of the first
  series but included stories with social and environmental issues,
  particularly in the second series where the children try to stop a big
  corporation from destroying their island.


Hi, no I'm sure it was 'Ocean Star'. Thanks anyway.
